# Changing the start number of an ordered list dependent of a query string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, math, html-lists

I have an `<ol>` and wish to set the `start` attribute dependent on a query string called `pagesearchresults`. The results break onto a new page every 10 results.

This would be fine if I wanted to set the `start` exactly as per the query string, as I can just extract it using a macro in my CMS, Kentico.

However, I want the `<ol>` to start at 1 on page 1, 11 on page 2, and so on. The formula for this in Excel would be `=A1-1&"1"`, for example.

I can see that some small amount of math is usable here - `start="1-1"` returns a `start` of 0, for example. Is there a way of achieving an equivalent of the Excel formula I outlined above in a html attribute?

Comment: You will need to use Javascript or a server side language such as VB (.NET) or PHP or similar!

Comment: Just coming to a similar conclusion myself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it! My code is below - it's very specific to my example (it includes the {?pageresults?} macro from Kentico), but you should be able to reverse engineer a solution if you're coming up against a similar issue. Requires jQuery, for neatness:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  var x=({?pagesearchresults?}-1)+"1"
  if (x<"1"){x="1";}
  $('#search_results').attr( 'start', x );
  });
</script>
<h3>Search Results</h3>
<ol start="" id="search_results">
```